# Save IplImage (not IplImage*) using cvSaveImage

Tags: c, opencv

I want to save an IplImage (not IplImage*) using the code bellow

```
IplImage ipl_from_mat((IplImage)imgDisparity8U); 
cvNamedWindow("window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); 
variable when you need it as IplImage* 
cvShowImage("window", &ipl_from_mat);  
cvSaveImage("disparity.jpg",ipl_from_mat);//Problem with this line
```

But it seems that it cant be possible . PLease help me.

Thanks and Regards
Somu

Comment: did you just try `cvSaveImage("disparity.jpg", &ipl_from_mat);` ? Just sending address instead of the value?

Comment: Yes I just tried it , now it is working.

Answer (score 6):

It's impossible you must to pass a pointer like this:

```
cvSaveImage("disparity.jpg", &ipl_from_mat);
```

Comment: If this answers the question, you should accept it as the answer (click the tick to the left of the question).